# Failed to sync gradle project: Unable to find method DefaultSourceDirectorySet

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.2 and trying to import a repository from `https://android.googlesource.com/`.

I get the following error when trying to sync with the given gradle file:

```
Gradle sync failed: Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet
```

I've attempted the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020929/android-studio-2-1-3-defaultsourcedirectoryset-issue#39051075) by updating the protobuf version to `0.8.0` but I get more errors: `Execution failed for task ':generateDebugProto'`

This is the gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.7.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.launcher3"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testApplicationId "com.android.launcher3.tests"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = ['res', 'WallpaperPicker/res']
            java.srcDirs = ['src', 'WallpaperPicker/src']
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            proto.srcDirs 'protos/'
        }

        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
            res.srcDirs = ['tests/res']
            manifest.srcFile "tests/AndroidManifest.xml"
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf.nano:protobuf-javanano:3.0.0-alpha-2'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
}

protobuf {
    // Configure the protoc executable
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0-alpha-3'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the protobuf section of your gradle file with the following:

```
protobuf {
    // Configure the protoc executable
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
    }
    plugins {
        lite {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                remove java
            }
            task.plugins {
                lite { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```